# How to update JLabels with numbers

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Alright, so i have two text fields where you type two numbers, then below those two text fields is a label called result that will display the amount once they are added together. At the bottom of the window is a button to add. Im having trouble updating the result label, below is just my action listener for my add button displayed. Everything displays perfectly fine from my code, i just need to know how to update my result label to display the sum of the two numbers. This is all in java btw.

```
addButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            double newNum1 = 0;
            double newNum2 = 0;


            String num1 = leftOperand.getText();
            String num2 = rightOperand.getText();



            if(!(num1.trim().equals("")) || !(num2.trim().equals("")))
            {
                newNum1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
                newNum2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
            }


            sum = newNum1 + newNum2;
            JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");
            resultLabel.setText("Result = " + String.valueOf(sum));
        }

    });
```

Here is the code that I used to create the result label. Just in case you need to see it.

```
JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");

resultLabel.setName("resultLabel");
resultPanel.add(resultLabel);

frame.add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

NOTE: these are both in the same method.

Comment: Hint: what does `JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");` do?

Answer (score 3):

First, make `resultLabel` an instance variable...

```
public class MyAwesomeClass extends ... {
    private JLabel resultLabel;
```

When building your UI, make sure you use it instead of creating a local variable

```
//JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");
resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");
```

When calculating the result, use the instance variable

```
//JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result =");
resultLabel.setText("Result = " + String.valueOf(sum));
```

Get back to basics and take a look at [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) and [Declaring Member Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)